# Find similar strings and reconcile them within one dataframe

Tags: r, string, dataframe, match

Another question for me as a beginner. Consider this example here:

```
n = c(2, 3, 5)
s = c("ABBA", "ABA", "STING")
b = c(TRUE, "STING", "STRING")
df = data.frame(n,s,b)

n     s      b
1 2  ABBA   TRUE
2 3   ABA  STING
3 5 STING STRING
```

How can I search within this dataframe for similar strings, i.e. ABBA and ABA as well as STING and STRING and make them the same (doesn't matter whether ABBA or ABA, either fine) that would not require me knowing any variations? My actual data.frame is very big so that it would not be possible to know all the different  variations.

I would want something like this returned:

```
> n = c(2, 3, 5)
> s = c("ABBA", "ABBA", "STING")
> b = c(TRUE, "STING", "STING")
> df = data.frame(n,s,b)

> print(df)
  n     s     b
1 2  ABBA  TRUE
2 3  ABBA STING
3 5 STING STING
```

I have looked around for agrep, or stringdist, but those refer to two data.frames or are able to name the column which I can't since I have many of those.
Anyone an idea? Many thanks!
Best regards,
Steffi

Comment: The rule of string replacement or grouping is not clear to me.

Comment: Similarity between strings, such as a few letters or numbers different. From what I understand from my browsing, some packages allow you to state the degree of similarity between strings. My original strings would be much longer, such as NYE,J.,SOFTPOWERANDAMERICANFOREIGNPOLICY(2004).... and JOSEPH,S.,NYE,J.,SOFTPOWERANDAMERICANFOREIGNPO....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me but there might be a better solution

The idea is to use a recursive function, `special`, that uses `agrepl`, which is the logical version of approximate grep, https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.4.1/topics/agrep. Note that you can specify the 'error tolerance' to group similar strings with `agrep`. Using `agrepl`, I split off rows with similar strings into `x`, `mutate` the `s` column to the first-occurring string, and then add a grouping variable `grp`. The remaining rows that were not included in the `ith` group are stored in `y` and recursively passed through the function until `y` is empty.

You need the `dplyr` package, `install.packages("dplyr")`

```
library(dplyr)

desired <- NULL
grp <- 1
special <- function(x, y, grp) {
                if (nrow(y) < 1) {        # if y is empty return data
                     return(x)
                } else {
                     similar <- agrepl(y$s[1], y$s)      # find similar occurring strings
                     x <- rbind(x, y[similar,] %>% mutate(s=head(s,1)) %>% mutate(grp=grp))
                     y <- setdiff(y, y[similar,])
                     special(x, y, grp+1)
                }
           }

desired <- special(desired,df,grp)
```

To change the stringency of string similarity, change `max.distance` like `agrepl(x,y,max.distance=0.5)`

#### Output

```
  n     s      b grp
1 2  ABBA   TRUE   1
2 3  ABBA  STING   1
3 5 STING STRING   2
```

To remove the grouping variable

```
withoutgrp <- desired %>% select(-grp)
```

Comment: Thanks! This unfortunately returns this error code : Error in mutate(., s = head(s, 1)) : could not find function "mutate"  Do I need to load a package I am unaware of?

Comment: I thought it is perhaps part of an agrep package, but there I get this error code: Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘agrep’ is not available (for R version 3.4.1)

Comment: Fantastic, that works splendidly! This is saving me so much time. Final question, where in your code do you exactly specify the error tolerance?

Comment: Hi, so this works all really well if I only use a few rows of my 1374x1301 data.frame. However, if I run it on the whole data.frame, this error code appear:  Error: cannot allocate vector of size 320 Kb . Google suggests this might have to do with running out of memory. Is the fact that it is a recursive function the problem? Any way to change that to a loop? Many thanks!

Comment: Yes this sounds like an issue with memory. Try to free up <1 MB of RAM.

Comment: I have freed up as much RAM as I could in terms of background programs, but I can only use the code on 8 rows, not more. I don't know how else to free RAM, I do have a  memory.limit() of 8072. Should I subset my data.set into some 230 data.frames?

Comment: Are you saying your data is 8 GB? `object.size(df)`. If so, you should not read your entire data in all at one time and you should subset

Comment: no sorry, > object.size(Split.CR): 25614552 bytes. I guess I need to start subsetting then. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Actually, that does not make some much sense for then I can only do the command in a limited set of rows and will still have too much variation. That is bad luck!