# how can I group based on similarity in strings

Tags: r

I have a data like this

```
df <-structure(list(label = structure(c(5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    9L, 10L, 4L), .Label = c(" holand", " holandindia", " Holandnorway", 
    " USAargentinabrazil", "Afghanestan ", "Afghanestankabol", "Afghanestankabolindia", 
    "indiaAfghanestan ", "USA", "USAargentina "), class = "factor"), 
        value = structure(c(5L, 4L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 10L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 
        8L), .Label = c("1941029507", "2367321518", "2849255881", 
        "2913128511", "2927576083", "4550996370", "457707181.9", 
        "637943892.6", "796495286.2", "89291651.19"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("label", 
    "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

I want to get the largest name (in letter) and then see how many smaller and similar names are and assign them to a group

then go for another next large name and assign them to another group

until no group left

at first I calculate the length of each so I will have the length of them

```
library(dplyr)
dft <- data.frame(names=df$label,chr=apply(df,2,nchar)[,1])
colnames(dft)[1] <- "label"
df2 <- inner_join(df, dft)
```

Now I can simply find which string is the longest

```
df2[which.max(df2$chr),]
```

Now I should see which other strings have the letters similar to this long string . we have these possibilities

**Afghanestankabolindia**

it can be

```
A
Af
Afg
Afgh
Afgha
Afghan
Afghane
.
.
.
```

all possible combinations but the order of letter should be the same (from left to right) for example it should be `Afgh`and cannot be `fAhg`

so we have only two other strings that are similar to this one

```
Afghanestan
Afghanestankabol
```

it is because they should be exactly similar and not even a letter different (more than the largest string) to be assigned to the same group

The desire output for this is as follows:

```
label                     value     group
Afghanestan              2927576083     1
Afghanestankabol         2913128511     1
Afghanestankabolindia    1941029507     1
indiaAfghanestan        796495286.2     2
 Holandnorway           457707181.9     3
 holand                 89291651.19     3
 holandindia            4550996370      3
USA                     2849255881      4
USAargentina            2367321518      4
USAargentinabrazil      637943892.6     4
```

why indiaAfghanestan  is a seperate group? because it does not completely belong to another name (it has partially name from one or another). it should be part of a bigger name

I tried to use this one [Find similar strings and reconcile them within one dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45510001/find-similar-strings-and-reconcile-them-within-one-dataframe) which did not help me at all

I found something else which maybe helps

```
require("Biostrings")
pairwiseAlignment(df2$label[3], df2$label[1], gapOpening=0, gapExtension=4,type="overlap")
```

but still I don't know how to assign them into one group

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try

```
library(magrittr)
df$label %>% 
  tolower %>% 
  trimws %>% 
  stringdist::stringdistmatrix(method = "jw", p = 0.1) %>% 
  as.dist %>% 
  `attr<-`("Labels", df$label) %>% 
  hclust %T>% 
  plot %T>% 
  rect.hclust(h = 0.3) %>% 
  cutree(h = 0.3) %>% 
  print -> df$group
```

[image]

```
df
# label       value group
# 1           Afghanestan   2927576083     1
# 2       Afghanestankabol  2913128511     1
# 3  Afghanestankabolindia  1941029507     1
# 4      indiaAfghanestan  796495286.2     2
# 5           Holandnorway 457707181.9     3
# 6                 holand 89291651.19     3
# 7            holandindia  4550996370     3
# 8                    USA  2849255881     4
# 9          USAargentina   2367321518     4
# 10    USAargentinabrazil 637943892.6     4
```

See `?stringdist::'stringdist-metrics'` for an overview of the string dissimilarity measures offered by stringdist.