# how can I perform a function with once happening across all pairs

Tags: r

I asked a question here which is very difficult to tackle [how can I group based on similarity in strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47609644/how-can-i-group-based-on-similarity-in-strings). I found a great idea and I want to give it a try.

Here is my thought and data (the same data as that question)

```
df <-structure(list(label = structure(c(5L, 6L, 7L, 8L, 3L, 1L, 2L, 
    9L, 10L, 4L), .Label = c(" holand", " holandindia", " Holandnorway", 
    " USAargentinabrazil", "Afghanestan ", "Afghanestankabol", "Afghanestankabolindia", 
    "indiaAfghanestan ", "USA", "USAargentina "), class = "factor"), 
        value = structure(c(5L, 4L, 1L, 9L, 7L, 10L, 6L, 3L, 2L, 
        8L), .Label = c("1941029507", "2367321518", "2849255881", 
        "2913128511", "2927576083", "4550996370", "457707181.9", 
        "637943892.6", "796495286.2", "89291651.19"), class = "factor")), .Names = c("label", 
    "value"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -10L))
```

1- I try to calculate the number of letter per each string in each row 
2- I try to perform a `adist` between each pair

if the output of `adist`is similar to the 1, they belong to one group, if no they are in two different group

to solve the above question, I need to know how to perform `adjst`on all string of the first column of my data.

so my question is the following

1- is there a function that does opposite to adjst ?
2- how can I perform adjst across all combination (for one time based on the longest to shortest , for example,

```
adist("Afghanestankabolindia","Afghanestan")
adist("Afghanestankabolindia","Afghanestankabol")
adist("Afghanestankabolindia","indiaAfghanestan")
adist("Afghanestankabolindia","Holandnorway")
adist("Afghanestankabolindia","holand")
adist("Afghanestankabolindia","holandindia")
.
.
.
```

The tricky part is that it should happen once between the reference and the other one for example, it should calculate only once the distance between

```
Afghanestankabolindia and Afghanestan
```

and not

```
Afghanestan and Afghanestankabolindia
```

Means the reference is always the longest string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really sure what your expected output format is, but I think this does what you want:

```
ref = as.character(df$label)
all_combs = as.data.frame(t(combn(ref[order(nchar(ref),decreasing = T)],2)))
all_combs$val = mapply(adist,all_combs$V1,all_combs$V2)
```

First, we create all combinations (sort the `ref` vector so first element is always the longer one (i.e. the reference). Then we use mapply to calculate `adist` for all combinations.

Output:

```
                      V1                  V2 val
1  Afghanestankabolindia  USAargentinabrazil  15
2  Afghanestankabolindia   indiaAfghanestan   15
3  Afghanestankabolindia    Afghanestankabol   5
4  Afghanestankabolindia        Holandnorway  17
5  Afghanestankabolindia       USAargentina   17
6  Afghanestankabolindia        Afghanestan   10
7  Afghanestankabolindia         holandindia  13
8  Afghanestankabolindia              holand  16
9  Afghanestankabolindia                 USA  21
10    USAargentinabrazil   indiaAfghanestan   16
11    USAargentinabrazil    Afghanestankabol  13
12    USAargentinabrazil        Holandnorway  14
13    USAargentinabrazil       USAargentina    7
14    USAargentinabrazil        Afghanestan   15
15    USAargentinabrazil         holandindia  13
16    USAargentinabrazil              holand  16
17    USAargentinabrazil                 USA  16
18     indiaAfghanestan     Afghanestankabol  10
19     indiaAfghanestan         Holandnorway  14
...               .....                .....  ..
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: thank you very much, I liked and accepted your answer